# Normalize.css V1 vs. V2 when support required for both older and newer browsers

Tags: css, normalize

I know there are two version of [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) and V2 is for IE8+, Firefox 4+, Safari 5+, Opera, Chrome. If i use version 1.1.2 over 2.1.2 in project because it should be compatible with all browsers IE7 and under along with cross-browser compatibility among older browsers, then what are the disadvantage of not using 2.1.2.

Comment: I've no idea why this question was closed. Seems perfectly reasonable to want to know the trade-offs between the two versions. Running a diff tool on the two versions, I can see that the `<q>` element has different normalisation for newer browsers in the two versions but not much else. Of course, the normalisations may diverge more in the future. The files are not long, I suggest running a diff for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There are several changes to V1 - But here is a list of the progression and changes leading to V2 and the finalization of V2. [Compare](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/compare/v1...master)

You can see the minute differences and changes. However, the links that Amruth provided are also very helpful - You can see V2 drops support for older browsers.

All in all - V2.1.2 has support for IE 8+, Firefox 4+, Safari 5+, Opera, Chrome. V1.1.2
Includes legacy browser support (support for 'older' browsers).

Comment: That I know but what was the benefit to make V2? Was it just to save some bytes by remove IE6/7 css?

Comment: It's only really to offer support for new browsers - I would also expect something MORE, but offering support for new browsers is crucial as they change just as we change underwears every day.

Comment: Exactly! :) And also because some of the older tags messed up the new browsers.

Comment: @AmruthA.Pillai - Could you please any example of older tags messing with newer browsers?

Comment: I believe Amruth is speaking about deprecated tags

Comment: Jitendra Vyas: What @LloanAlas said, deprecated! :) Here's a list of deprecated tags/attributes in HTML5: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_deprecated_tags.htm

Comment: @AmruthA.Pillai As far as I remember no styling was defined for deprecated tags in Normalize.css

Comment: I believe it's more about the inconsistencies between browsers - You can't really support all new browsers and old browsers with all the differences in technologies. I personally wish there was something that made it so there was support across the board - but as of today, I have found nothing that does that.

Comment: The only thing coming close to making IE an acceptable browser is Google's Chrome Frame. I make sure to add the snippet to all the websites I code :)

Comment: @AmruthA.Pillai Google is retiring "Chrome Frame"

Comment: Just saw that. Sad. I guess the only option now is to add a <=IE8 comment with a notice on the website to tell everyone to update their browsers.

Comment: @Amruth A. Pillai: The versions of IE that need Chrome Frame aren't going to be relevant for much longer. Why is it sad that Google no longer has to waste time maintaining a project that will soon become obsolete?